# Xcode update stuck after updating macOS

Tags: xcode, app-store, updates, macos-high-sierra

After updating macOS,

[image]

I cannot update XCode anymore:

[image]

[image]

I have been waiting for 2 hours but AppStore does not update.

How do I restart the Xcode update process from the beginning?

Regards

Comment: You can download the `.xip` directly → [Xcode_9.3.xip](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.3/Xcode_9.3.xip)

Comment: same problem, High Sierra 10.13.4 XCode 8.2 (8C38)

Answer (score 50):

It updated successfully, after around 5 hours. I just did nothing, just left it there.

Comment: Lol, well this certainly is an answer.

Comment: Xcode 12.3 took about 45 minutes to get to the last sliver of the progress wheel, then it sat with that tiny little bit left doing nothing for another 45 minutes before finally finishing.  This answer kept me patient.

Comment: yes I kept awaiting and it went to completion

Comment: Same for XCode 13.

Answer (score 43):

It is painfully slow when it comes to the 'Installing' stage.

Based on the log from `console`, it does not look like it is spinning empty.

For example, progress from 94.67% to ...

[image][image]

... 94.83% took almost 20 sec

Comment: How did you find this `console`?

Comment: Just search for 'Console' in Spotlight (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014)

Comment: Thanks! Did you filter by the process name somehow?  `appstoreagent` and `storedownloadd` don't seem to return any logs.

Comment: well, you can always try `xcode` I suppose? It's too long ago I don't remember.

Comment: I filtered by the `storedownload` process was returning logs for me. Also using [caffeinate](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-stop-your-mac-from-sleeping-using-the-command-line--mac-50905) `caffeinate -w <pid>`, I made sure the computer didn't turn off during the long wait time.

Comment: Ouch!!! Really slow... I'm using a 300+-Mbs Download internet connection and this is what I'm getting:

896 / 1000 - After 1 minute
898 / 1000...

Really slow process.

Comment: That 'console' comment just saved my sanity after 3 reboots! I thought nothing was happening. Thanks a lot @Anthony Kong

Comment: You can also just open a terminal and `tail -f /var/log/install.log`

Answer (score 40):

A lot of the pain of updating XCode from the App Store can be avoided by downloading the latest version from the Apple Developer website directly (including beta versions if you are into them). Use [this Apple Developer link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

For more information see [this Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234461/124013).

Comment: Can you still use App Store update after installing it like this?

Comment: @Sébastien Nope, you can not.

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with updating Xcode even after deleting it and trying to install it again via the App Store. For me it helped to switch to the **Purchased** tab in the App Store and cancelling all the other downloads (by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd> and then clicking **Cancel**). Then the download of Xcode started, hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a download running in background which would explain this waiting time.
I restarted a few times my Macbook pro, and ended up waiting until it ran the update successfuly.

When you make an XCode update, you have to do it when you have free time ahead, not during rushes, you never know how much time it can take

Answer (score 0):

Currently Xcode update from developer tools does not work. Also Xcode 9.3 after download the install gets blocked because the file is corrupted. Additional Tool for Xcode 9.3 downloads and install but then does not work either. App Store downloads Xcode and restart but then it is not functional 
Attempts:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
App Store

mac iOS developer tools

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having problems. I updated to XCode 9.3 from the Dev link provided last week though and had no problems. Updating High Sierra first was a pain, but not XCode itself.

Comment: Yes, I also filed a bug directly with Apple Developer platform and will update this issue,  once they reply. They require more deets. Thank you for your comment though very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*I had problem opening .**xcworkspace.** force quit application window showing it's not responding on **macos mojave**.*

*executed below commands after that it started working.*

```
/* remove saved app states for chosen applications*/
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState/

/* https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/is-it-safe-to-erase-library-developer */
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer
```

Comment: ```xcrun simctl erase all```. i did this too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my ISP has a slow connection when downloading from Apple's server. Try using VPN to get a faster connection.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xcode from App store was stuck for me as well it kept on showing rotating loader, I have to say their progress bar isn't the best indicator. Before losing hopes its always best to check the progress behind the curtain. You are going to need 'Console' app for this.

1. Search for 'Console' app from Spotlight Search.
2. Then go to search bar and type "App Store".
3. Next you need to click on start.
4. You will see a lot of activity in app store as it happens. You will see something like "Completed: 980 of 1000"(based on your progress). Monitor that and it will move.

So it's a better indicator rather than sitting and watching app store loading progress.

Comment: Yoy may see this line `ASDAppQuery.resultsDidChange 497799835: <NSProgress: 0x6000036e1cc0> : Parent: 0x0 (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 0.9260 / Completed: 926 of 1000`