# Xcode 12.3 not downloading or updating Big Sur - Multiple Mac Restarts

Tags: xcode, kernel, updates, store, restart

I have a problem with the Mac restarting sporadically, at random events. It then displays a warning on restart on Kernels. (Ironically, as I try to save a photo from another source on the same error message that appears to add photos to this question, it restarted!)

[image: warning on unwanted restart]

This has happened since updating to Big Sur 11.1, introducing the push feature with Github for an app in Xcode, attempting to update Xcode to the most recent edition and having a trojan virus on the mac. I have since (fingers crossed) located and eradicated the virus through Norton Anti-Virus, quarantined and deleted.

Since then, I have attempted to upgrade my Xcode to the most recent (12.3). Through the App Store menu for updating, or recent purchases, despite clicking to download the upgrade, it merely displays a stop option with no progress displayed. It does the same for Microsoft Outlook.

[image: download does not begin]

After reading that it could be hardware (no peripherals attached to devise) or software related issue, I have uninstalled Xcode by dragging to trash and emptying the bin, to download the whole programme from scratch. Clicking the download from cloud option in the App Store, the same result occurs, in the Developer section and in the purchased section.

I have gone to the apple developer website to download the app, as recommended here: [Xcode update stuck after updating macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584185/xcode-update-stuck-after-updating-macos).

My first download of Xcode 12.3, through google chrome, resulted in the download stopping for no apparent reason around 69mb, with a warning. I attempted to download again, this time with the download stopping around 2.8gb, with the same warning as previous;

`The archive "Xcode_12.3 (1).xip" is damaged and can't be expanded.`

[image: Xcode download stopped way before stated 10.8gb zip file size]

I ran an Ookla Speed Test returning 79gbps download and 7gbps upload speed, so I would hope it is not my internet connection.

The Mac continues to randomly restart, despite, when searching for OS updates, I am told I have the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a discussion with Apple Help, they recommended the following approach.

1. I backed up user data and files
2. Run a First Aid Disk Utility repair
3. Conduct a SMC restart by unplugging the mac and then plugging in again after 15 seconds.
4. Then reset the NVRAM/PRAM on startup by holding OPT+CMD+P+R immediately on startup until system loads.
5. The next step was to reinstall macOS Big Sur. So far, no need to as the restarts have stopped, and the app updates have completed.